# Create iTunes-like grid view connected to Core Data on OSX

Tags: cocoa, macos, core-data, interface-builder, cocoa-bindings

I am an experienced iOS developer interested in creating a Mac application. I want to create a grid view of data connected to my Core Data store via bindings, which, like iTunes, should by default only display a subset of the total data columns, but allow the user to choose to add more columns from the database to be displayed, move them around, etc. OSX has a number of grid-like GUI elements, e.g. NSTableView, NSOutlineView, NSCollectionView, etc. Which of these is the best to create such a view?

Comment: `NSCollectionView` would fit your purpose, I belive.

Answer (score 2):

The NSCollectionView item cannot handle large amount of data, since it does load all the views even though they're not visible at the moment. If you use for more than 500 elements (or a few more), you will get an unusable view and a lot of errors in the Console.

You should always prefer the [IKImageBrowserView](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/graphicsimaging/Reference/IKImageBrowserView/IKImageBrowserView_Reference.html) for displaying large amounts of data, that is included in the Quartz framework. I think that iTunes uses this.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about the NSCollectionView, it is pretty new, I am sure you can make exactly what you want with an NSTableView. It really has more to do with the cells that you implement and keeping track of your control Cells.  Check out the [core data application demo](http://developer.apple.com/cocoa/coredatatutorial/index.html), if that isn't what you want you can follow @sudo rm -rf to:

the [NSCollectionView programing guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/CollectionViews/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009030)